# What is the order of the Cliché choices in combat?

Tags: risus

I'm attacking an enemy. Let's assume we both have several appropriate Clichés. Each combatant choose a Cliché and then make their roll:

> Attacks require rolls against character Clichés.

What if my choice depends on the enemy choice? Who chooses first? Should we choose blindly?

Comment: There might be a rule for this in the Risus Companion, which I keep meaning to get (it's not free like the core rules).  Have you looked there?  Otherwise, perhaps someone can contact S. John Ross, the game author.

Comment: The Companion has a section on initiative, which boils down to 'It doesn't matter'. And you should get it, or maybe wait for the second edition.

Comment: @Chuk I can't find the word "initiative" in the Companion, do you mind specifying the page number?

Comment: It's on page 33 under "Order Out of Chaos". (Searching the PDF, I didn't see the word either, but it's quite clearly in the first paragraph and the first bullet point. Weird.)

Answer (score 5):

If you initiate combat, then you choose the cliché that defines the encounter and it's up to the enemy to respond with an appropriate cliché (if they have one). Bear in mind though that this means the person who initiates combat can never have an inappropriate one, only the defender.